# can I get the text direction from the culture code?

Tags: c#, cultureinfo, culture, hebrew, right-to-left

If I have the culture code for a country/language combination, is it possible to from this, find the text direction.

For example for en-US how can I get from this that the text direction is left to right? And in turn from ar-EG, how do I know the text direction is right to left?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can easily be done using the `TextInfo.IsRightToLeft` property of `CultureInfo`

Example:

```
CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ar-EG").TextInfo.IsRightToLeft; // Return True
CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us").TextInfo.IsRightToLeft; // Return False
CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("he-il").TextInfo.IsRightToLeft; // Return True
```